# downloading csv from google drive using R

Tags: r, download, rcurl

I have a file on the googledrive the first few lines look like this:

[image]

I want to download it in my working directory using R. Here's my approach

```
  library(googledrive)

 # authenticate google drive 
  drive_auth()

  dd <- drive_find(pattern = paste0(year_ref,"_mainland"))

   A tibble: 1 x 3
   name                                  id                                drive_resource  
  * <chr>                                 <chr>                             <list>          
   1 1987_mainland_2020-08-20_21:11:55.csv 1OqBA5ZLKDmo6l1nsMa39XpqOIg_Oa72P <named list [38~

  drive_download(dd, verbose = TRUE) 

  Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
    Failed to open file C:\googletest\1987_mainland_2020-08-20_21:11:55.csv.
```

What possibly could be the reason that this is not working?

**EDIT**

However, when I download my csv, remove the last column `geo`, change the file name to `test.csv` and re-upload it and try to download it again, it downloads. Is there something wrong in my original csv column name or the actual file name?

Comment: try `drive_download(as_id(dd$id), verbose = TRUE)`, if you are trying to do several you'll need to loop through with your preferred method. I use `walk()`

Comment: It still gives me same error. However, when I download my file, remove the last column `geo` and re-upload it and try to download it again, it downloads. Is there something wrong in my original csv?

Comment: That's interesting. You could try the argument `path = "test.csv"` in drive_download to replace the file name you are saving to. I know windows is upset with : in path names, but I don't know your OS. It might be you have the polygon data in the geo with the commas between coords, so you can try switching the formatting to tab delim instead of csv if the file rename doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add: my original file name is `1987_mainland_2020-08-20_21:11:55.csv` and if I change the file name to `1987_mainland_2020-08-20.csv`, it works. I think it does not like the time stamp towards the end. Let me try your suggested approach and see if it works

Comment: I did this and it solved: `drive_download(file = as_id(dd$id), 
               path = file.path(getwd(),'test.csv'),
               verbose = TRUE,
               overwrite = TRUE)`

Comment: Happy you got there